# Will Upgrading to Windows 8.1 Disable Drivers?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1

I'm hearing that most AMD Graphics users are mad because windows 8.1 disabled their drivers. Is that true ?

Comment: You will need to update your drivers if you update. The driver model for Windows 8.1 was updated.  I am not sure the reason somebody would get mad over something that takes less then 5 minutes to resolve.

Comment: God, forgive me I had to restart my computer...

Answer (score 0):

Moving to 8.1 can remove some of your drivers, but you'll eventually find some that'll fit to 8.1, some of the 7 ones or 8 ones can fit into 8.1...

Answer (score 0):

Although some amd windows 8 drivers don't automatically work with windows 8.1, they have released drivers that do work.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Do note - there is a chance after you go through the choices SYSTEM/FAMILY/PRODUCT/OS that an 8.1 driver isn't listed for your device (as happened to me).

If you look on the right hand side of this same page, there are links to windows 8.1 drivers. These DO work.. just choose the one that describes your graphics most accurately.